# Can ssh internally, but not externally

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I have a Netgear C6300 (Firmware Version 2.01.14) router/modem, and I'm trying with all my might to ssh into my raspberry pi externally. Here's my port forwarding setup:
[image]

I can ssh internally using `ssh 192.168.0.84`, but externally on canyouseeme.com I get "Error: could not see your service on  on port (22). My sshd_config has the line `Port 22` and the `ListenAddress` lines are commented out. In other words, I have not touched this file. What is going on here?

Comment: Note: this is absolutely a duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/1019256/can-ssh-internally-but-cant-externally-port-22-connection-refused but that question is 5 months old with no answer, so I'm asking again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things come to my mind.

The forwarding in your screenshot looks OK. You could try to set it to `TCP` instead of `TCP/UDP`, because ssh is a TCP protocol.

#### dyndns

Are you sure that you use the correct dynamically updated hostname or your correct public IP address? To find your public IP address, open a console on the Raspberry or SSH (internally) into it and use `curl icanhazip.com`.

#### sshd_config

Make sure, in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, that sshd listens to the correct interface, in case you have multiple. Comment out the line `ListenAddress a.b.c.d` with a `#` and restart the service (`/etc/init.d/sshd restart` or `systemctl restart sshd`, depending on your distro).
Edit: sorry, you already said that.

Edit:

#### routing

If you cannot get an output from `curl icanhazip.com`, chances are that your Raspberry does not know how to get to the internet. So it cannot reply to your connection attempt from the outside. Add a route, e. g. with `ip route add default via <your modem's IP address>` and try again.

#### iptables

Make sure that your Raspberry-internal firewall allows SSH from external addresses. `iptables -S` will give you a list of rules. Look for lines like

```
-A INPUT -s 192.168.0.0/24 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
# SSH only allowed from the internal network, if iptables policy INPUT is DROP
```

In that case, allow all incoming traffic with either `iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT` or `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT`.

#### DS-Lite (Dual Stack Lite)

Internally, in your home network, you use IPv4 addresses. In your example 192.168.0.x. However, your ISP might use IPv6 in his network. The router translates your IPv4 addresses to IPv6. This usually results in the inability to connect to your home network from remote.

If `curl icanhazip.com` gave you an IPv6 address, e. g. `2001:a61::35:2`, it might be an indicator. Also, maybe your C6300 will show information about that. (I use an AVM Fritz!Box 7360, and it explicitly outputs "Fritz!Box uses a DS-Lite tunnel").

To be 100% sure, call your ISP.

Edit:

In case you are behind a DS-Lite tunnel, the following options come to mind to nevertheless connect back home from remote:

- ask your provider/ISP to switch your line to a non-DS-Lite one
- use `autossh` to have your home computer connect to another host, e. g. at work (ask your employer before), your web server, your VPS. Configure `autossh` in a way that it creates a reverse tunnel, e. g. `ssh -R 10000:localhost:22 user@yourvps.com`. Then you can ssh to yourvps.com and ssh from there back home via `ssh -p 10000 user@localhost`.

Edit:

#### Netgear C6300 specific

There seems to be a bug in firmwares until or up to Firmware Version 2.01.14 which will make opened ports visible only if the option "Respond to Ping on Internet WAN Port" in the "Advanced Configuration" > "WAN Setup" is activated.

[image: Netgear C6300 WAN Setup]

Comment: My `iptables -S` output is just `-P INPUT ACCEPT` `-P FORWARD ACCEPT` `-P OUTPUT ACCEPT`, so I ran `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` as you suggested and while the `curl` command did output an IPv6 address, using that made no difference. I set the protocol in my port-forwarding to TCP, but http://www.ping.eu/port-chk/ still tells me the port is closed.

Comment: OK. Well, if all policies (`-P`) already were set to `ACCEPT`, there was no difference. If `curl` outputs an IPv6 address, then chances are, that you are running a DS-Lite stack. Or better, your ISP does. Please have a look at their webpage, customer forums, or call them, to be 100% sure. In that case, it might be hard to get a connection from remote to home. You could rent a VPS with a public IP and run `autossh` on your Raspberry, so that you can jump from the VPS to your Raspberry at home.

Comment: *frowns* there has to be a way I can use an open service to connect to a machine I own using an internet connection I already pay for without renting anything. My former housemate had a fileserver based out of my house, we changed routers but not ISPs since then, so it has to be possible, because we've done it before.

Comment: This is new information! How long ago did your housemate run the fileserver? What kind of fileserver was that? Which ports did the fileserver use? Can you try to have SSH listen on a different port, e. g. 80 or 443, forward the port correspondingly in your router and try again?

Comment: Did you activate "respond to ping on internet WAN port" in "Setup" > "WAN Setup" in the Advanced Configuration?

Comment: I keep forgetting to take a screenshot, but changing the WAN Setup to respond to pings and allow port scans was what worked

Comment: Glad that my questions and answers worked for you. Please feel free `accept this answer` or to ask more new questions here on superuser. :)

Comment: ip route add default via <your modem's IP address> - this solved the problem for me. Thanks !